# Will the Codeiginiter SQLServer Connection always persists ? Can a connection be non persistent from Codeigniter for MSSQL Connection

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

Why SQL Server @@spid is same for all session when connecting from Codeigniter 3.0 PHP ?

I have successfully connected to  SQL Server from Codeigniter 3.0.2. I am using the sqlserv Driver. 
Why is the SQL Server @@spid always returning the same for different user sessions.
My database connection is not set to Persist.
How can i make it not persist.  Here is my DB connection.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'Testdb',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

I tried the same for Mysql Connection from codeigniter. It works  non persistent as  expected. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to the below link, 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc644930%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Connection Pooling (Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server)

The following are important points to note about connection pooling in the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server:

```
The Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server uses ODBC connection pooling.

By default, connection pooling is enabled. When you connect to a server, the driver attempts to use a pooled connection before it creates a new one. If an equivalent connection is not found in the pool, a new connection is created and added to the pool. The driver determines whether connections are equivalent based on a comparison of connection strings.

When a connection from the pool is used, the connection state is reset.

Closing the connection returns the connection to the pool.
```

I could resolve the  problem by setting

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'Testdb',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

when i set pconnect' => TRUE , 'app_id'=>''.rand() during connection , 
new @@SPIDs are created.

So by effectively setting the 'app_id' , it is possible to control the pooling for application  or by users groups or by users

caution:By setting  pconnect' => TRUE , 'app_id'=>''.rand()  , you are effectively nullifying the effect of connection pooling in your application.
A careful use  is recommended.

Comment: You realize you made your application slower for no real reason by doing this? :)

Comment: @Mjh. Thank you,  i realised after posting my answer that by making this i am not effectively using connection pooling. This was a test, i was doing to understand the connection pooling :) .